# Invalid path to image on Magento 2

Tags: magento2

1. I save my image `dark.jpg` to: `app/disign/frontend/Vendorname/default/web/images`.
2. `rm -R pub/static/*`
3. `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
4. Go to `site admin panel/home page/content`, write `<img src="images/dark.jpg">`.
   But this not work (Not Found). **What is the right path should I write?**

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean app/**design** not app/d**i**sign but your final path should be:

```
pub/static/frontend/Vendorname/themename/languageCode(ie:"en_US")/images/dark.jpg
```

If your vendor and theme name is Fuzzy/bunnies and code is en_US your relative path would be

```
<img src="pub/static/frontend/Fuzzy/bunnies/en_US/images/dark.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! But it not work. If you change local, image not found